# Compare 2 arrays and show results

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have 2 arrays with different number of elements, the case is, I want get show the same element have the 2 arrays.

For Example :

```
$search_terms="house,car,boy,table";
$cats="1,2,3,4,car,boy,fly,girl";

$explode_term=explode(",",$search_terms);
$explode_tags=explode(",",$cats);   

$compare=array_diff_assoc($explode_term, $explode_tags);

foreach ($compare as $compa)
{

    print $compa;
    print "<br>";   

}
```

As you can see I have 2 arrays and only have some elements in common, by this I want to get the element it´s the same in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

```
array_intersect($explode_term, $explode_tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_terms="house,car,boy,table";
$cats="1,2,3,4,car,boy,fly,girl";

$explode_term=explode(",",$search_terms);
$explode_tags=explode(",",$cats);   

$compare=array_diff_assoc($explode_term, $explode_tags);

foreach ($compare as $compa)
{
    print $compa;
    print "<br>";   
}
```